# Use JQuery to Modify external JS File

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know if this possible so I apologize in advance if this question comes off as being a little ignorant. 
I am working a website that must use a template and server-side languages such as PHP are disallowed. There is an external JS file on the website that I would like to modify but I cannot figure out how to access/modify it from the main script using JQuery.

In case that was not clear, here is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<script src="fileToModify.js"></script>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>code to modify external file goes here</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In the above example, I would like to be able to place code (in JQuery/JS/some other language like that) where it says "code to modify external file goes here" and alter the local copy of "fileToModify.js" (for example, to delete a function within it). I am aware that, if successful, such a deletion could not alter the real file hosted on the server; I am only trying to alter the local copy when the user downloads it to change how it behaves after the page loads).

Would such a task be possible with JQuery/JS/something of the sort?

Thanks for your help

Comment: you cannot modify a file on a server with javascript alone. You could fetch the file contents and put into a string and modify it and then eval() it but that could cause issues.

Comment: @PatrickEvans I know - as stated above, I would like to modify the local copy of it after the browser downloads the external JS file (not the real file hosted server-side)

Comment: javascript does not have access to the temporary files, or file system for that matter. There is the File System Api but its not widely implemented and i do not know if it even lets you to request access to  those areas.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Oh. That is what I was asking. Thanks for telling me that, good to know and unfortunately means that my task will probably be impossible

Comment: Well you could do what i suggested grab the contents of the js file through ajax modify them and then eval them, but again like i said that could open up security holes if not handled properly.

Comment: @PatrickEvans I am not particularly concerned with security holes, this is more of an experiment. Thank you for your insight and help and  I will attempt to do so

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use ajax to get the contents of the file (and not execute it), then do use javascript to replace some of the data. Then you could use `eval` to execute it.

```
$.ajax({
  method: 'GET',
  dataType: 'text',
  url: 'to-modify.js'
}).then(function(data) {
  data = data.replace('bar();', '')
  eval(data)
})
```

**[Live demo (click)](http://plnkr.co/edit/bL8V0GLyz0vnmyTA9meJ?p=preview)**

Comment: That would be most helpful if you could make a demo :)

Comment: Thank you for the helpful demonstration, it should be most useful